# Changes to local firebase.json not reflected when restarting Firebase server

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've been messing around locally with Firebase Hosting url rewrites but for some reason none of the changes I make to my local `firebase.json` seem to work. I know hot reloading only works for files in the public directory so I've been manually restarting the server using `firebase serve` but still no dice. I even tried entirely removing one of my rewrites to see if the route would disappear from my local server but it didn't. Has anybody else experienced this? When I make changes and deploy them they work, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with my changes being invalid. I'm rewriting urls to use Firebase Cloud Functions in case that's relevant.

Edit: here's my config (function and file names have been changed). I was removing rewrites and changing the source path for rewrites but none of it was reflected locally.

```
{
    "functions": {
        "predeploy": [
            "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
        ]
    },
    "hosting": {
        "public": "functions",
        "rewrites": [
            {
                    "source": "/folder/file.js",
                    "function": "getFile"
            },
            {
                    "source": "/folder/otherFile.json",
                    "function": "getOtherFile"
            }
        ],
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the configuration that doesn't work the way you expect.  As it stands now, there's nothing we can do to help you because we don't know what you're expecting to happen with your setup.

Comment: Does it work for you if you make rewrites to a non-function resource? i.e. just rewriting to another URL?

Answer (score 0):

By default, your locally hosted app will interact with real, not local, project resources. That is, the deployed version of your firebase.json will be referred to and not the changes you made locally. If you want to test changes to your config locally, you would be required to deploy locally using the firebase emulator which will deploy your application to localhost:5000 by default and the changes can be tested here.

```
firebase emulators:start
```

For more information refer to the firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy)